# Is there a way to link a Joomla PHP login page to a C# ASP.Net login function (will be used for SharePoint login with Basic auth)?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5, joomla, sharepoint-2013

I'm currently developing a C# MVC Web API to act as a middleman between a Joomla 3.6 site and a SharePoint 2013 server, both installed in IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2. Both the Joomla 3.6 site and SharePoint 2013 are already set up and functional, SharePoint has an active development site already set up, and I'm currently working on a SharePoint app/C# ASP MVC Web API to handle any requests between Joomla and SharePoint. This app handles any request, including logins (which are to be verified against Active Directory on a server), file upload/download, and searching users/documents/tags, among others. The C# app/web API endpoints are also only allowed to be called by users logged into the system, except for login.

My question becomes this, then. Put simply, is there any way I can tell the Joomla 3.6 website, when a user attempts to log in to the system (using the login page), to call my login endpoint and/or somehow authenticate with the SharePoint 2013 server? Preferably, I'd like to use my own C# login endpoint to interact with SharePoint in this case, unless that is not possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Find a SAML authentication plugin for Joomla and use ADFS from Active Directory as "login page / somehow authenticate".

Comment: @FlorinAsăvoaie Do you have any plugins you'd recommend off-hand?

Comment: Not a big fan of Joomla but I'm sure there are some out there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a mechanism provided via Joomla plugins.  I've developed authentication plugins for several third party services.

You would develop a user plugin which hooks into the onAuthenticate event, allowing you to intercept and authenticate the user without them being the wiser.

If you need to add additional fields to login for (i.e. domain) you can also hook into the onContentPrepareForm event and add, alter or remove form fields

This is also one use-case where there is pretty decent documentation available.

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_an_Authentication_Plugin_for_Joomla
https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events